# tensorflow resize nearest neighbor approach don't optmize weights

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm beginner in tensorflow and i'm working on a [Model](http://hi.cs.waseda.ac.jp/~iizuka/projects/colorization/data/colorization_sig2016.pdf) which Colorize Greyscale images and in the last part of the model the paper say :

> Once the features are fused, they are processed by a set of
>   convolutions and upsampling layers, the latter which consist of simply
>   upsampling the input by using the nearest neighbour technique so that
>   the output is twice as wide and twice as tall.

when i tried to implement it in tensorflow i used `tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor` for **upsampling** but when i used it i found the cost didn't change in all the epochs except of the 2nd epoch, and without it the cost is optmized and changed

**This part of code**

```
def Model(Input_images):

   #some code till the following last part

    Color_weights = {'W_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,256,128])),'W_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,128,64])),
             'W_conv3':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,64,64])),
             'W_conv4':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,64,32])),'W_conv5':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,32,2]))}

    Color_biases = {'b_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128])),'b_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),'b_conv3':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
            'b_conv4':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),'b_conv5':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2]))}    

    Color_layer1 = tf.nn.relu(Conv2d(Fuse, Color_weights['W_conv1'], 1) + Color_biases['b_conv1']) 

    Color_layer1_up = tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor(Color_layer1,[56,56])

    Color_layer2 = tf.nn.relu(Conv2d(Color_layer1_up, Color_weights['W_conv2'], 1) + Color_biases['b_conv2']) 
    Color_layer3 = tf.nn.relu(Conv2d(Color_layer2, Color_weights['W_conv3'], 1) + Color_biases['b_conv3']) 

    Color_layer3_up =  tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor(Color_layer3,[112,112])
    Color_layer4 = tf.nn.relu(Conv2d(Color_layer3, Color_weights['W_conv4'], 1) + Color_biases['b_conv4']) 

    return Color_layer4
```

**The Training Code**

```
 Prediction = Model(Input_images) 
    Colorization_MSE = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(Prediction,tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,112,112,32]))))
    Optmizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate= 0.05).minimize(Colorization_MSE)
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()    
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) 
    for epoch in range(EpochsNum):
        epoch_loss = 0
        Batch_indx = 1
        for i in range(int(ExamplesNum / Batch_size)):#Over batches
           print("Batch Num ",i + 1)
           ReadNextBatch()
           a, c = sess.run([Optmizer,Colorization_MSE],feed_dict={Input_images:Batch_GreyImages})
           epoch_loss += c
        print("epoch: ",epoch + 1, ",Los: ",epoch_loss)
```

So what is wrong with my logic or if the problem is in
`tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor` what should i do or what is it's replacement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solved it, i noticed that tf.random normal was the problem and when i replaced it with tf.truncated normal it is works well